# How to escape Semicolon in django rest framework GET Request

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

i'm new for Django REST Framework,help me to escape semicolon in django rest framework GET Request.
i'm using postman tool for GET request

**Input Request.**

[image]

**Response output is**

[image]

If you check second image input text after semicolon text(hello)  is removed ,so i have lost my original input text as i sended get request.help me achieve this.

**Requested code**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some code, like how you are handling the request data? Django Rest Framework doesn't require to handle semicolon as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi  Paras Nath Chaudhary thanks for response ,please check my updated post i have attached  requested code.Thanks

Comment: Semicolon works a delimiter in URL similar to '&' character. So, if you want to send semicolon character in the url you will have to use the urlencoded value i.e. %3B.

Comment: Pls help me how  to use it in above code.

Comment: This means that you don't have to do anything in your Django code. It's up to the developer who is going to consume the API. The developer who implements the API should do the URL encoding of the query parameters before making the GET request. However, if you don't want to use the URL encoded value you can decode the URL encoded parameter using urllib package.  URL encoding based on the language used to consume the API. For example, in python you would do:
import urllib
urllib.urlencode(input_text_variable)
And to decode 
urllib.parse.urlencode(inputData)